# Error when exeuting BCP: BCP host-files must at least contain one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I want to use BCP in my database. For that purpose I wrote this query:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT rtrim(ltrim(anumber)),rtrim(ltrim(bnumber)),rtrim(ltrim(duration))  FROM [CDRDB].[dbo].[CDRTABLE]"  queryout d:\myOUT.txt -S . -UCDRLOGIN -Pbeh1368421 -f "d:\myFORMAT.fmt"  '
```

The format file `myFormat.fmt` detail is this:

```
9.0
3
1 SQLNCHAR 0 5 "," 1 ANUMBER "" 
2 SQLNCHAR 0 10 "," 2 BNUMBER ""
3 SQLNCHAR 0 10 "\r\n" 3 DURATION ""
```

When I run the BCP command I get this error:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try running your select statement first? You might need to alias those column names like this: `rtrim(ltrim(anumber)) as Column1` though that's just a guess. You might also want to react your login and password from your sample code.

Comment: i change rtrim(ltrim(anumber)) as anumber and ... but so not work

Comment: With regards to the 'unable to resolve column level collation confilct' error, there are a lot of suggestions on the internet to run `BCP -V`  and ensure your BPC version matches the SQL Server you are extracting from. So try that and edit your question with the results. Also it may help to post the table DDL (including collation definitions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `-S .` switch. I don't think that's enough for SQL Server. Execute the following in SSMS:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME;
```

And use the output of this query instead of the `.`.

Second, is there really a need for the format file? You could supply following switches instead: `-w -t, -r\r\n`

```
DECLARE @stmt VARCHAR(8000)='bcp "SELECT rtrim(ltrim(anumber)),rtrim(ltrim(bnumber)),rtrim(ltrim(duration)) FROM [CDRDB].[dbo].[CDRTABLE]" queryout "d:\myOUT.txt" -UCDRLOGIN -Pbeh1368421 -w -t, -r\r\n -S ' + @@SERVERNAME;
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @stmt;
```